# Email Validation with IdentityUser in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, validation, identity

I recently updated my API to support Asp.NetCore.Identity. Therefor i had to remove a lot of fields in my User class because they already exist in the IdentityUser class, from which User inherits.

In my old User class i validated for string length and email using DataAnnotations.

```
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }
```

In my new class i tried overwriting the existing fields with my own and add the Annotations but this does not work. 
How do you validate fields with IdentityUser?

Jakob

Comment: You should be more specific about *when* do you want it to be validated. It's not the model itself that does the validation, but the code consuming it. Do you use `IdentityUser` as a model for data submitted from user?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use UserValidator

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{

    public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context) 
    {
        UserManager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(UserManager) {  };

        //you can override validator or validation for specific property
    }
}
```